# How do I group routes using http.ServeMux?

Tags: go

I want to create a very small API using the `ServeMux` from the `http` package. There are some routes I want to group together, all of them should have a prefix. I tried this sample code

```
import "net/http"

func GetAPI() *http.ServeMux {
    apiMux := http.NewServeMux()

    group := http.NewServeMux()
    group.HandleFunc("/foo", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })
    apiMux.Handle("/my-group", group)

    // other apiMux routes go here

    return apiMux
}
```

I tried to test it via

> http://localhost:8080/my-group/foo

but unfortunately I get a 404. How do I group routes correctly?

Comment: `apiMux.Handle("/my-group", group)` matches only `/my-group`.  If you want to match everything under `/my-group`, you need `/my-group/` with a trailing slash.  The problem is that `group`'s router expects to match the full path of the URL.  If you add the `/my-group` prefix to `/foo`, it will work at `/my-group/foo`.  You can strip the `/my-group/` prefix with http.StripPrefix, but then you'll be redirected to `/foo`. https://go.dev/play/p/6CGZ9LOrJYL

Answer (score 0):

Try more like the following which answers differently on localhost:8080/ and localhost:8080/my-group

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

type apiHandler struct {
    mu   sync.Mutex // guards Data
    Data string
}

func (api *apiHandler) ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    api.mu.Lock()
    defer api.mu.Unlock()
    api.Data = "Hello, World!"
    // log.Println("apiHandler.Data:", api.Data)
    fmt.Println("apiHandler.Data:", api.Data)
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/my-group/", &apiHandler{})
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // The "/" pattern matches everything, so we need to check
        // that we're at the root here.
        if req.URL.Path != "/" {
            http.NotFound(w, req)
            return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the home page!")
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  OP wants to put routes under one Mux under a tree in another Mux.  You're not doing that here; your inner handler is not a Mux and doesn't route.

Answer (score 0):

If the only feature of the group is the common prefix, then use string concatenation on the path instead of nested muxes.

```
func SetupMyGroup(mux *http.ServeMux, prefix string) {
    mux.HandleFunc(prefix+"/foo", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "foo")
    })
    mux.HandleFunc(prefix+"/bar", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "bar")
    })
}

...

mux := http.NewServeMux()
SetupMyGroup(mux, "/my-group")
SetupOtherGroup(mux, "/other")
```